# Magento and Microsoft RMS integration

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, api, integrate

Does anyone have a recommendation for integrating with Microsoft RMS? I'm looking to sync products (and inventory count) between the two systems, as well as pass sales orders from Magento to RMS. I've read up on some extensions on the Magento site that claim to do this but I was wondering if anyone in this forum can share their experience working with them, or with attempting this kind of integration themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with integrating with Microsoft RMS but in general when connecting these kind of systems look for a company that offers at least some level of service.

Since you might not be too proficient in the Microsoft RMS systems you'll need someone that does know how it works. 9 out of 10 times the client has some custom fields or settings in their system that give issues with the integration and figuring that out without a good working knowledge of BOTH platforms it can be quite time consuming.

As for the Magento extensions themselves; I don't know what their price is but buying them and doing a quick code review might be wise or look for a company that you know to write good code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are still looking for a solution but we built a connector that helps sync

- product information
- stock data
- product images
- product categories
- customer data

from RMS to Magento and

- download latest orders
- download customers

from Magento to RMS

It is working well on production environment already and this is a screenshot from the application

[image: slack notification for Magento RMS integration]

We are going to install the connector directly on the machine you use to run RMS so it is extremely easy for deploying.

If you need more information of the product, please feel free to take a visit here:

[Magento Dynamics RMS Integration](https://www.beehexa.com/products/magento-2-microsoft-dynamics-retail-management-system-integration/)

we also provide some other [magento erp integration](https://www.beehexa.com/products/magento-2-integration/) products, if you need your magento website to work with ERP or any 3rd party applications.